# Get rid of uncaught exception

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a piece of software, which is written in `Racket`, where I want to use a very very simple exception handler: when an exception is thrown, the handler print out a message and the application terminates.

I can reproduce the behaviour in the following toy example:

```
(define (body) 
  (begin
    (displayln "First line")
    (error "Some error")
    (displayln "This line is not printed")))

(call-with-exception-handler (lambda (x) (displayln "Exception handler")) body)
```

The output of this code is:

```
First line
Exception handler
uncaught exception: #<void>
```

I want it to quit just after the `displayln` expression, in the exception handler (i.e. the expression which prints `"Exception handler"`). How can I do that?

Comment: After _which_ `displayln` expression? you have two of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(with-handlers ([exn:fail? (lambda (exn)
                             ; in case you need the error message
                             (displayln (exn-message exn))
                             (displayln "Exception handler"))])
  (displayln "First line")
  (error "Some error")
  (displayln "This line is not printed"))
```

It'll print:

```
First line
Some error
Exception handler
```